# Git - How to maintain a C# solution as GitHub repo with variations for specific customers

Tags: git, github

We have a base solution developed in C#. Many times, we make customer specific changes. For such "customizations", we make a copy of the base solution folder, name it as per the client, and do the code changes. The base solution and client specific solution are about 90% identical.

How should we maintain this solution in GitHub?

1. Should we create a monorepo, with subfolders for the base solution
   and for each client specific solution?
2. Should we create separate repo for the base solution and for each
   client specific solution?
3. Should we create a single repo for the base solution and maintain
   branches for each client? In this approach, how should we maintain
   release cycle for each branch? For each customer, we will need a
   main branch, qa branch and prod branch.

The base solution gets enhanced over time with new feature additions. These enhancements need not be immediately added to client specific solutions which are already deployed, unless the client comes back with a feature request or sales team sells the new feature to existing clients.

Any strong pros or cons?

The potential number of clients for the base solution can be around 100-200.

EDIT 1:

The client specific changes could be something like adding a few additional columns to a business report which are relevant only to that client's business or industry, or preparing some fields of an API payload from a different source field based on the client's implementation or usage of the software, etc.

Comment: This is a really common question; I can see a fair few titles that look relevant [searching for "git branch per client"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branch+per+client). One common piece of advice is to avoid this approach if at all possible: use git to manage _versions_, and some application-specific mechanism like _feature flags_ or _plugins_ to manage client-specific functionality.

Comment: The problem with feature flags can be that over time, the base application can become overly complicated with many conditional paths, and analyzing change impact of changing a feature can be time consuming. Moreover, in future, if we change the UI completely in the base application and decide on completely new workflows or sequence of steps, many clients' specific code with the legacy workflow will simply have to be carried in the codebase.

Comment: Feature flags are supposed to be short lived, from a few weeks to a few months. But in our case, the client specific changes can stay for much longer duration.

Comment: The client specific changes could be something like adding a few additional columns to a business report which are relevant only to that client's business or industry, or preparing some fields of an API payload from a different source field based on the client's implementation or usage of the software, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

other [link](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255) that is more superficial